# Moving robots in a 2D grid in constant time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

So i'm trying to figure out an algorithm problem where i've got a 2D array representing a grid in which there are multiple robots and a flag.

Robots can move one cell at a time in every direction (left, up, right, down) but every bot should move the same direction every time.

When a robot go out of the array bounds, it's eliminated.
When a robot arrives on the cell in which there is the flag, it's saved (and removed from the grid).

Example :

```
grid:
    | R1 |    
--------------
    |    | R2 
--------------
    | D  |    

> move(left)
grid:
 R1 |    |
--------------
    | R2 |
--------------
    | D  |

> move(down)
grid:
    |    |
--------------
 R1 |    |
--------------
    | D  |
saved: [R2]
```

We can find a very simple algorithm in time complexity O(width*height) where width and height are the dimensions of the array, but i need a solution in constant time complexity that can moves all the robots in any direction.

Do you guys have an idea how could i do that ?

Comment: What exactly is the goal? Save as many robots as possible? Get all robots from the grid?

Comment: Do you have proof that O(1) is possible in advance of asking or are you just hoping it's possible? That means I can get the robots off a 1000000x1000000 grid just as quickly as a 4x4 grid. Also, what's your "simple algorithm"? I'm not clear on the purpose/goal of the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

You have the WIDTH and HEIGHT of the grid (aka 2d array).
You have the starting positions of the "robots" X and Y.
You have the direction the "robot" is moving UP (Y - 1), DOWN (Y + 1), LEFT (X - 1), RIGHT (X + 1).
You have the position of the "flag" X and Y.

Seems like you'd have to loop through N number of the robots, so it's really not CONSTANT time but if we ignore that...

```
// Move the robot
IF Move == UP THEN Robot.Y -= 1
ELSE IF Move == DOWN THEN Robot.Y += 1
ELSE IF Move == LEFT THEN Robot.X -= 1
ELSE IF Move == RIGHT THEN Robot.X += 1
// Check for out of bounds
IF Robot.X < 0 OR Robot.X >= WIDTH OR Robot.Y < 0 OR Robot.Y >= HEIGHT THEN Robot.Disappear()
// Check for flag
IF Robot.X == Flag.X AND Robot.Y == Flag.Y THEN Robot.Save()
```